# How to cure music influence on mind?

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities

Namo Buddhaya.I have a habit of playing involuntary songs in my head which spoils my mood. I am a living library of songs. I have been hearing music since my childhood days.
My question is : how can I cure the music influence on my mind ? 
Should I stop listening to songs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These songs in the mind are hindances. To stop them, yes, stopping listening to songs.

> *And what is the nutriment for the five hindrances? It should be said: the three kinds of misconduct. The three kinds of misconduct, too, I
> say, have a nutriment; they are not without nutriment. And what is the
> nutriment for the three kinds of misconduct? It should be said:
> non-restraint of the sense faculties. Non-restraint of the sense
> faculties, too, I say, has a nutriment; it is not without nutriment.
> And what is the nutriment for non-restraint of the sense faculties? It
> should be said: lack of mindfulness and clear comprehension. Lack of
> mindfulness and clear comprehension, too, I say, has a nutriment; it
> is not without nutriment. And what is the nutriment for lack of
> mindfulness and clear comprehension? It should be said: careless
> attention. Careless attention, too, I say, has a nutriment; it is not
> without nutriment. And what is the nutriment for careless attention?
> It should be said: lack of faith. Lack of faith, too, I say, has a
> nutriment; it is not without nutriment.*
>
> [*AN 10.61*](https://suttacentral.net/an10.61/en/bodhi)